# Minor on visitor visa returning to India from Australia with grandparents

Tags: india, paperwork, australia, malaysia, minors

My nephew (6 years old) is returning from Australia to India with his grandparents. He, his parents and grandparents came over on a visitor's visa for vacation. His parents left after a week.

Will he require any specific documents when travelling back to India with his grandparents? He will be travelling back via Singapore or Malaysia.

I checked http://smartraveller.gov.au/guide/Pages/travelling-with-children.aspx - it says children travelling alone, with guardians or parents just need their visa and passport, but the way I read it, it seems to be for Australian citizens travelling out and it's not clear what documents are needed to state that the grandparents are guardians (copies of the parent's passports enough?).

Also (I can't seem to find it now), but I recall seeing something about a Letter of Consent (I believe this too was for Australian citizens travelling out).

Would the same documents suffice for India and Singapore / Malaysia?

Answer (score 2):

As the child entered Australia accompanied by both parents and grandparents, departing with the latter shouldn't be an issue, nor should airside transit points. Should the child's visa only reference the parents, it may be a good idea to add a photocopy of their passports' identity page to the consent letter.

While they may not be on a Quantas flight, [this advisory](https://www.qantas.com/travel/airlines/travel-documents/global/en) is helpful:

> Accompanying adult must write the full name of the child on the reverse of the adult's boarding pass, so that the minor can be linked to the accompanying adult and their identification.

As for arrival home, portions of the [AirIndia for Minors travelling with passengers other than their natural parents](http://www.airindia.in/minors-travelling-with-passengers-other-than-their-natural-parents.htm) are a good guide (although not all might be necessary).

> The following should be borne in mind when a child / infant is accompanied by other adults and not traveling with their parents.
>
> - Consent (no objection) letter/affidavit signed by both parents ([draft attached](http://www.airindia.in/Images/pdf/Child_travel_no_objection_letter.pdf))
> - Photocopies of relevant pages of both parents passports
> - Signatures of the parents on consent letter should match the signature on the passport
> - In the rare case where the family name of the child does not match the parents', birth certificate of the child should be made available